Is it correct to use the simplified formula P(t) for the truncated normal distribution law?
For our studies, we have a guidebook that includes a formula for the truncated normal distribution: $$
P(t) = \frac{0.5 - \Phi \left( \frac{t - m}{\sigma} \right)}{0.5 + \Phi \left( \frac{m}{\sigma} \right)}
$$I used it for a task with the following conditions:
The operational time of a car generator follows a truncated normal distribution with the parameters m = 8000 hours, σ = 1000 hours  . It is necessary to find the probability of failure-free operation for 10,000 hours, the failure rate for 6,000 hours, the failure intensity for 10,000 hours, and the mean time to the first failure. I got a value of -0.318, which cannot be correct for a probability. After that, I used the standard formula for the truncated normal distribution:
$$P(t) = \frac{\Phi \left( \frac{t - m}{\sigma} \right) - \Phi \left( \frac{0-m}{\sigma} \right)}{1 - \Phi \left( \frac{0-m}{\sigma} \right)}
$$ I got the result of 0.9972, and I was able to continue solving the problem. Am I missing something? Or is the simplified formula simply incorrect in this case due to the large value of
? Next, I solved another problem on normal distribution, using the formula:$$P(t) = 0.5 - \Phi \left( \frac{t - m}{\sigma} \right)
$$ I got correct values, but they differ significantly from the results for the standard normal distribution formula. Is it correct to use simplified formulas? Even if we are using them for learning, I don’t see a difference from using standard formulas because they always work. Am I missing something?

What is $P$ exactly? "Formula for x distribution" is ambiguous, as there are multiple ways to characterise a distribution: cdf, pdf, mgf etc. And for good measure what is $\Phi$?

P(t) is the probability of failure-free operation up to time t. In this context, I’m using the cumulative distribution function (CDF) to describe the probability that a random variable (e.g., time to failure) is less than or equal to t.
Φ(z) is the standard normal CDF, used for calculating probabilities in normal distribution problems.
I’m specifically using the CDF, not the PDF or MGF, since the task involves failure-free operation probabilities.

$P(t)$ cannot be a probability for all $t$ as it can take negative values for some values of $t$. Is it possible that your definition of $P$ is incomplete?

The thing is, by using the simplified version of the formula P(t) that I provided, we end up with the possibility of negative values because we are not taking the full probability as in the standard formula '1', but rather half of it—0.5. This is why, for the case of P(10,000), I ended up with a negative value using my formula. From what I understand, I think that using such large parameters is not suitable for the simplified formula, or maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Truncated Normal is too vague, to which set or manifold is it truncated? If I refer to the middle-of-the-page equation, it seems to be truncated to $(0,\infty)$

And why you need an approximation to such a simple cdf requires explanations.

To clarify, yes, the truncated normal distribution in our case is truncated to  (0,∞) because the time to failure cannot be negative. This truncation is necessary since we are working with operational times, and it doesn't make sense to consider negative values.

As for the simplified formula, it's part of the guidebook used in our studies, likely intended to make calculations easier for students. However, as you pointed out, using this approximation doesn't seem necessary, especially when the exact cumulative distribution function (CDF) is relatively straightforward to work with. In fact, I agree with you that sticking with the standard formula is better, as it provides correct and consistent results even for larger  z-values.

I sometimes use tricks like mirroring cfd's, especially computing F(-x) = 1- F(x) for symmetric distributions. It could be that this is some background for your formula, but it doesn't make much sense. If $t$ increases, then $P(t)$ decreases. Did you make typo's?

I carefully reviewed my calculations, and it seems there are no typos in the formula. I agree with you that as t increases, the probability P(t) should decrease. In my calculations, this trend holds true when using the correct formulas.

@Simon didn't you refer to P(t) as the CDF? The CDF should be an increasing function.

Your function makes little sense as a CDF or something related (e.g. survival function).
Consider some special cases
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
t \to -\infty &\rightarrow& P(t) = \frac{1}{1+2\Phi(m/\sigma)}\
t = m &\rightarrow& P(t) = 0 \
t>m &\rightarrow& P(t) < 0
\end{array}$$

I apologize, I'm just a complete idiot… we are using not $$ P(t) = \frac{0.5 - \Phi \left( \frac{t - m}{\sigma} \right)}{0.5 + \Phi \left( \frac{m}{\sigma} \right)}
$$ but $$ P(t) = \frac{0.5 - \Phi_0 \left( \frac{t - m}{\sigma} \right)}{0.5 + \Phi_0 \left( \frac{m}{\sigma} \right)}
$$ After finding   we need to find $$ \Phi_0(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} , dz
$$

@Simon that still doesn't make sense. Possibly you are after $\Phi_0(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} , dz$ but still it doesn't make sense.
